# Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton for API Level 19

Tags: java, android, migration, androidx

Implementation 'com.google.android.material: material: 1.0.0'

But I get the error in the header when I run api19 on a device.

For this:

```
<style name = "Theme.MyApp" parent = "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
<style name = "Theme.MyApp" parent = "Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
```

I tried the methods but did not get a result. How can I solve this?

In other android versions, there is no problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/google_login_button"
        app:icon="@drawable/google"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        android:text="@string/google_button_text" app:cornerRadius="@dimen/login_screen_button_radius"/>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        app:icon="@drawable/facebook"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/google_login_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/twitter_login_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/facebook_button_text" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:cornerRadius="@dimen/login_screen_button_radius"/>

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
        app:icon="@drawable/twitter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/facebook_login_button"
        android:text="@string/twitter_button_text" app:cornerRadius="@dimen/login_screen_button_radius"/>
```

Comment: There's more to that error.

Comment: Are all these drawables inside `drawable` folder or in folders like `drawable-v21`?

Comment: drawable in folder. activity 2 things have activity_main.xml and activity_main.xml (21)

Comment: @Yavuz I don't understand what you replied. Just make sure that all drawables are inside the `drawable` folder.

Comment: @forpas I deleted the relevant images, but the problem persists

Comment: You did not have to delete them, just make sure that they are also inside the drawable folder. Now post the error log.

Comment: i have same error

Comment: @Yavuz post the error log.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{developers.remindertodoapp/developers.remindertodoapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

Comment: Post the whole part beginning with these lines inside your question, not in the comments.

Comment: I was having a similar issue a dew minutes ago, this is happening because you need to use the new material components theme as the theme of the activity. Like `Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar` you will not get the errors.

Answer (score 10):

I know its a bit late but for those who will face this problem in future. Change your AppTheme parent to Theme.MaterialComponents

Before

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

After

```
<!-- Material application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: It's doesn't answered OP question. He clearly have `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge` your answer not a solutions to the problem he mentioned.